# Draw a Rectangle in Java

Tags: java, swing, shapes

I want to draw a rectangle in Java on a Swing application, but I don't know how. I have looked at similar questions, none containing the answer I need. I have tried the following:

```
private void paintComponent(Graphics graphics, Rectangle rect, Color color) {
    contentPane.paintComponents(graphics);
    Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D) graphics;
    graphics2D.setColor(color);
    graphics2D.draw(rect);
}
```

I call it like:

```
contentPane = new JPanel();
contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
contentPane.setLayout(null);
paintComponent(contentPane.getGraphics(), new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50), Color.WHITE);
```

But it throws a `NullPointerException` on this line:

```
graphics2D.setColor(color);
```

I suspect it is the `graphics2D` being `null`. How can I fix this?

Comment: `getGraphics` is null until the component is visible.

Comment: That being the case, just check graphics for null and just return if it is.

Comment: Never use getGraphics, you don't control the paint process, it's done for you, you just need to plug into it to be notified when an update is required...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not even overriding the method correctly. `paintComponent` only takes a `Graphics` object as an argument, so you can't add your own.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test extends JPanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new Test());
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.pack();
            }
        });
    }

    public Dimension getPreferrdSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawRect(10, 10, 150, 40);
    }
}
```

Comment: With the use of a layout manager, the call to Test#setSize is irrelevant, better to override getPreferredSize. You should also be creating your UI from inside the content of the Event Dispatching Thread

Comment: Yeah, I know. I was just trying to demonstrate the concept.

Comment: That's cool, then you should also make the attempt to demonstrate the correct way of achieving the entire result, otherwise you're just propergating more bad code, and the Internet is full of that...

Comment: What do you mean the entire result? He wanted to draw a rectangle, that's all there is to it.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by UI from inside the content of the Event Dispatching Thread?

Comment: Using prefeeredSize over setSize, starting the UI within the context of the EDT, showing how it should be done from start to finish so as not to encourage bad habits. If you were teaching someone to shoot, would you only tell them where the trigger was or would you also tell them about basic gun safety and  aiming as well...?

Comment: [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

Comment: So can you port my code to satisfy your conditions for my own understanding, and paste an answer below.

Comment: I looked at an example [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step1.html) and I was wondering how this event dispatcher is any different from simply called the method.

Comment: Hope you don't mind, update your answer. In the example you've linked to, check the difference between your main method and the examples, the main difference is the use of InvokeLater which ensures that the UI code is called from within the context of the event dispatching thread

Comment: And what exactly is the event dispatching thread? Aren't swing applications inherently threaded?

Comment: NO! Swing is single threaded. It has its own thread (the EDT), which is responsible for processing the Event Queue, including paint events. Swing is also NOT thread safe, which can lead to dirty paints or corruption of data if updates are not synchronised correctly to the EDT.